# Derivatives (divergence, gradient, curl) of interpolated 3D data

Tags: interpolation

How can I calculate a vector derivative (i.e. divergence, gradient, curl) of interpolated data? For sample data, you can use:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Exp[I z] {1, 0, 0}
testdata=Flatten[Table[N@{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]},{x,0,4 Pi,Pi/10},{y,0,4 Pi,Pi/10},{z,0,4 Pi,Pi/10}],2];
intf = Interpolation[testdata]
```

I know that for 1D data, like

```
dim1 = Table[N@{z, f[0, 0, z]}, {z, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}];
int1 = Interpolation@dim1;
```

you can do `D[int1[x],x]`. However, I can't seem to get convince MMA that the interpolated function `intf` actually returns a "vector" quantity (i.e. `Length@intf[x,y,z]->3`), so that I can do something like:

```
curl = {D[#[[3]],y]-D[#[[2]],z],-(D[#[[3]],x]-D[#[[1]],z]),D[#[[2]],x]-D[#[[1]],y]}&;
curl@intf[x, y, z]
(* Out[] := {0,0,0} *)
```

Similarly, this should work for gradient:

```
grad = {D[#[[1]], x], D[#[[2]], y], D[#[[3]], z]} &;
```

and divergence:

```
div = (D[#[[1]], x] + D[#[[2]], y] + D[#[[3]], z])&;
```

I've posted my best attempt in an answer below, but I'm wondering what other solution approaches there are.

Comment: Is there a typo in the last component of the curl, should that be `D[#[[1]], y]`?

Comment: @ruebenko yup. good catch. fixed it.

Comment: have you looked at `Derivative` for this. e.g. `Derivative[0,0,1][intf][x,y,z]`. (I have to go now, so I can not post a solution)

Comment: From the help `D[f, {{x1, x2, ...}}] gives the vector derivative`

Comment: @belisarius J.M. pointed that out in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6051146#6051146), but I've been having trouble getting it to work with the interpolated functions.

Comment: @EliLansey hehe .. me too. The eval order is driving me nuts :)

Comment: @belisarius Yeah. And I've never been strong with the `Hold`'s stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another possibility. First compute the derivatives (this should use formal symbols for safety, but I've used `x,y,z` here to avoid cluttering the code)

```
intfd[x_, y_, z_] = D[intf[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}];
```

then define the curl by

```
intfcurl[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{q = intfd[x, y, z]},
  {q[[2, 3]] - q[[3, 2]], q[[3, 1]] - q[[1, 3]], q[[1, 2]] - q[[2, 1]]}]
```

The results seem okay:

```
intfcurl[0.4, 0.2, 0.3]
(*  {0., -0.297934 + 0.954217 I, 0. + 0. I}  *)
```

and the timing is reasonable:

```
intfcurl @@@ testcoords; // Timing
(*  {7.863, Null}  *)
```

---

You can similarly define the gradient and the divergence using `intfd`:

```
intfgrad[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{q = intfd[x, y, z]}, Diagonal[q]]
intfdiv[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{q = intfd[x, y, z]}, Tr[q]]
```

Comment: Nice. Using a `Module` fixes a lot of problems. Not sure why I didn't think of it. It's fast, too!

Comment: An alternative that I mentioned to Eli in chat: for the curl, form the skew part `jac - Transpose[jac]` from the Jacobian returned by `intfd[]`, and then extract the required entries to form the curl.

Answer (score 6):

The best I've been able to come up with is to separately interpolate each component of the vector data:

```
testdatacomps =Table[{Sequence @@ #[[1 ;; 3]], #[[4, n]]} & /@ testdata, {n, 1, 3}];
intcomps = Interpolation /@ testdatacomps;
```

Then

```
interpolatedcurl[xx_, yy_, zz_] := 
 curl@Through[intcomps[x, y, z]] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {xx, yy, zz}]
```

This result compares well to the actual curl:

```
curl@f[x, y, z] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {.4, .2, .3}]
interpolatedcurl[.4, .2, .3]
(* Out[1] := {0, -0.29552 + 0.955336 I, 0}
   Out[2] := {0., -0.297934 + 0.954217 I, 0. + 0. I} *)
```

**Edit** It is also reasonably fast. Evaluating at 10000 random coordinates:

```
testcoords = RandomReal[{0, 4 \[Pi]}, {10000, 3}];

interpolatedcurl @@@ testcoords; // Timing
(* Out[] := {11.451, Null} *)
```

Comment: Are you sure about the last component? The function depends only on `z`, and the z component of the curl contains derivatives in the other two coordinates ... I guess you didn't correct the third component after @ruebenko comment

Comment: @Verde Whoops, you're right! Let me fix that.

Answer (score 4):

```
(*Your definitions*)
f[x_, y_, z_] := Exp[I z] {1, 0, 0}
testdata =Flatten[Table[N@{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]},{x,0,Pi,Pi/10},{y,0,Pi,Pi/10},{z,0,Pi, Pi/10}],2];
intf = Interpolation[testdata]


(* A derivative operator *)

d[i_Integer][args__] :=(Derivative[Sequence@@ RotateRight[{1, 0, 0}, i - 1]] [intf])[x, y, z] 
                       /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {args}]

(*Curl*)

curl[a__] := Chop/@ {d[2][a][[3]] - d[3][a][[2]], 
                     d[3][a][[1]] - d[1][a][[3]], 
                     d[1][a][[2]] - d[2][a][[1]]}

(*Test*)
curl[.4, .2, .3]
(* 
{0, -0.297934 + 0.954217 I, 0 }
*)
```

Comment: This looks promising. I tried it, but I got `(*Part::partd: "Part specification 0.4[[3]] is longer than depth of object"*)`.

Comment: @EliLansey Works here ... Mma v 8.0.0.  Just in case, start a fresh kernel

Comment: yup, that fixed it.

Comment: From a timing standpoint, this is *way* slower than my version. I can run through 10000 points in 11 seconds using mine, but I got tired of waiting after 5 minutes. Not sure why yours takes so long.

Comment: It takes 11 seconds to go through 20 points using this method.

Comment: @EliLansey Ok. I think I know what is happening. Let me try to improve it