# Interpolation of data on non-rectangular grid

Tags: interpolation

I have a smooth data distribution on a 2D regular grid that is not a rectangular (it is a cross-section of a channel) and I need to find an Interpolating function `f[x,y]`.
I have tried `Interpolation[{{x1,y1},f1},{x2,y2},f2},...}]` but it doesn't work.
Does `Interpolation` work only on rectangular grid?

Thanks
Giovanni

Comment: Have you tried a search on this very site?

Comment: Or how about the Mathematica help? To give a short answer, `Interpolation` works not only on rectangular grids.

Comment: Please could you be more specific about the meaning of "doesn't work"? Also, see [(20372)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20372). (This was suggested by the review panel as a possible duplicate. Clearly the question is not a duplicate so I skipped the review, but the answer is highly relevant. I am leaning toward closing this as TL unless clarification comes from the OP.)

Answer (score 2):

`Interpolation` does not only work on rectangular grids. The grid even need not to be regular.

E.g. let us produce some data (x, y,z) which are not on a regular grid on a disk with radius of 5 in the x-y plane and which have z-values between 4 and 5 with:

```
radius=5;
maxRandomNumber=1000;
{x,y,z}=({#1*Cos[#2]*radius,#1*Sin[#2]*radius,#3})&[
Sqrt[RandomReal[{0,1},maxRandomNumber]],
2*Pi*RandomReal[{0,1},maxRandomNumber],RandomReal[{4,5},maxRandomNumber]];
data = Transpose[{x, y, z}];
```

If you plot them with

```
 ListPlot3D[data]
```

You get something like

[image: output of plot]

You can interpolate the data easily with

```
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Plotting them with

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < radius]]
```

Or

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < radius]]
```

give you a similar picture as the first one. So you see, interpolation still works for such data.

Comment: This does not work with dimensions greater than 4, e.g. data={{a,b,c,d,e}, ...} -> f[a,b,c,d]=e